# Problem with a normal

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Text of problem: "Define equation of curve, in all it points normal have the following feature: length of abscissa on the $x$-axis between beginning of coordinates and intersection of normal with $x$-axis equal to *square of* $y$-*coordinate of point*, in which normal was defined". I haven't slightest idea, how to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

The language makes some problems to me, but I think it means the following: let $\;y=f(x)\;$ be the wanted curve. We need that at any point on the graph, namely $\;(a,f(a))\;$, the normal to to the curve at this point, namely the line

$$y-f(a)=-\frac1{f'(a)}(x-a)$$

is such that the distance from the origin of its intersection point with the $\;x$-axis, i.e. from the solution of

$$(x-a)=f(a)f'(a)$$

equals $\;f(a)^2\;$ , so we need to solve the differential equation

$$f(a)^2=|f(a)f'(a)+a|$$